# $F_t$-measurable Random Variable and Information

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a filtered probability space $(\Omega,(F_t)_{t\geq0},P)$.

Let a stochastic process be a collection of random variables indexed by time $X:[0,\infty)\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $X_t$ is adapted, so it is $F_t$-measurable.

Then, is the following true if we consider the filtration to be information set?

$$E(X_{t+1}|X_t)=E(X_{t+1}|\text{all information up to $t$}).$$

Answer (score 2):

This is true for Markov processes. However, there are continuous-time non-Markov processes. For example, a fractional Brownian motion, i.e., a centered Gaussian process with covariance function
$$
\rho(t,s)=\frac{1}{2}(|t|^{\alpha}+|s|^{\alpha}+|t-s|^{\alpha}), \quad \alpha\in (0,2),
$$
is not a Markov process for $\alpha\ne 1$.